# How to convert a CSV file to List<Map<String,String>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a CSV file which has a header in the first line. I want to convert it to `List<Map<String, String>>`, where each `Map<String, String>` in the list represents a record in the file. The key of the map is the header and the value is the actual value of the field.
What I have so far:

```
BufferedReader br = <handle to file>;
// Get the headers to build the map.
String[] headers = br.lines().limit(1).collect(Collectors.toArray(size -> new String[size]));
Stream<String> recordStream = br.lines().skip(1);
```

What further operations can I perform on `recordStream` so that I can transform it to `List<Map<String, String>>`?

Sample CSV file is:

```
header1,header2,header3   ---- Header line
field11,field12,field13   ----> need to transform to Map where entry would be like header1:field11 header2:field12 and so on.
field21,field22,field23
field31,field32,field33
```

Finally all these Maps need to be collected to a List.

Comment: Could you post a sample CSV file with a sample output? I'm not sure I understand what should happen.

Comment: You can't skip the first line like that. You need the names of the columns. Don't use streams for this.

Comment: So is it not possible to do it with streams?

Comment: You can retrieve the header line with an ordinary `br.readLine()` invocation, followed by processing the remaining lines via `br.lines(). stream ops`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will work. The header line is retrieved by calling `readLine` directly on the `BufferedReader` and by splitting around `,`. Then, the rest of the file is read: each line is split around `,` and mapped to a `Map` with the corresponding header.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...)) {
    String[] headers = br.readLine().split(",");
    List<Map<String, String>> records = 
            br.lines().map(s -> s.split(","))
                      .map(t -> IntStream.range(0, t.length)
                                         .boxed()
                                         .collect(toMap(i -> headers[i], i -> t[i])))
                      .collect(toList());
    System.out.println(headers);
    System.out.println(records);
};
```

A very important note here is that `BufferedReader.lines()` does not return a fresh `Stream` when it is called: we must not skip 1 line after we read the header since the reader will already have advanced to the next line.

As a side note, I used a `try-with-resources` construct so that the `BufferedReader` can be properly closed.

Comment: the i in toMap function needs explicit typecast to Integer. This worked for me .collect(toMap((Integer i) -> headers[i], i -> t[i])))

Comment: As a side note I would still recommend to use libraries like [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to read CSV. [CSV format](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) supports quoting which allows having a comma inside the field. The provided implementation would read such files incorrectly.

Comment: @VivekKothari Maybe this is a bug of the IDE you are using. The code given in the answer compiles fine with Eclipse Mars and javac 1.8.0_51

Comment: I am using eclipse luna and  java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode). But I am getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but I ran into the same problem, and created a quick sample of the [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) solution mentioned by [Tagir Valeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856258/tagir-valeev):

```
            Reader in = new FileReader("path/to/file.csv");
            Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in);

            List<Map> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
            for (CSVRecord record : records) {
                listOfMaps.add(record.toMap());
            }
```